# Getting a cell from DataTable.Row.ItemArray with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ado.net

I have the following ItemArray:

```
dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.. //{0,1,2,3,4,5}
```

the headers are : item0,item1,item2 etc..

So far, to get a value from the ItemArray I used to call it by an index.

Is there any way to get the value within the ItemArray with a Linq expression based on the column name?

Thanks

Comment: You can do without linq by dt.Rows[0]["columnName"].ToString();

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to know how to do it with linq due to code maintance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use the column-name to get the field value:

```
int item1 = row.Field<int>("Item1");
```

- [DataRow.Item Property(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx)
- [`DataRow.Field Method:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Provides strongly-typed access

You could also use `LINQ-to-DataSet`:

```
int[] allItems = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  select row.Field<int>("Item1")).ToArray();
```

or in method syntax:

```
int[] allItems = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("Item1")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your comment. I don't fully understand the syntax here as I wished to perform this action on a specific row (lets say Rows[0]) how do I see it at your example?

Comment: @DavidRasuli: If you only have one row and you only want to get a specific field value, use the first method i've shown(`row.Field<int>("Item1")`). Otherwise explain what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [Item indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx) rather than `ItemArray`, you can access items by column name, regardless of whether you use LINQ or not.

`dt.Rows[0]["Column Name"]`

Answer (score 1):

Tim Schmelter's answer is probably what you are lookin for, just to add also this way using `Convert` class instead of `DataRow.Field`:

```
var q = (from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable() select Convert.ToInt16(row["COLUMN1"])).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with today solving a similar problem. In my case:
(1)I needed to xtract the values from columns named Item1, Item2, ... of **bool** type.

(2) I needed to xtract the ordinal number of that Item**N** that had a **true** value.

```
var itemValues = dataTable.Select().Select(
                r => r.ItemArray.Where((c, i) =>
                dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName.StartsWith("Item") && c is bool)
                .Select((v, i) => new { Index = i + 1, Value = v.ToString().ToBoolean() }))
                                        .ToList();


  if (itemValues.Any())
  {
        //int[] of indices for true values
        var trueIndexArray = itemValues.First().Where(v => v.Value == true)
                    .Select(v => v.Index).ToArray();
  }
```

forgot an essential part: I have a **.ToBoolean()** helper extension method to parse object values:

```
    public static bool ToBoolean(this string s)
    {
        if (bool.TryParse(s, out bool result))
        {
            return result;
        }

        return false;
    }
```